# Summation over indices from symarray

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

I'm attempting to created a symbolic expression by summing over indices in a tensor. For a matrix/2D tensor this is pretty simple:

```
from sympy import *

Q = MatrixSymbol('Q', 2,2)

i,j = symbols('i j')
summation(summation(Q[i,j],(i,0,2)),(j,0,2))
```

When I try to look at a fourth-order tensor I'm running into issues. Here's my attempt:

```
from sympy import *

Q = MatrixSymbol('Q', 2,2)
C = symarray('C', (2,2,2,2))

i,j,k,l = symbols('i j k l')
summation(summation(summation(summation(Q[i,j]*C[i,j,k,l],(i,0,2)),(j,0,2)),(k,0,2)),(l,0,2))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`C = sym.symarray('C', (2,2,2,2))` makes `C` a NumPy array of SymPy symbols.
Since `C` itself is not a SymPy Symbol, NumPy balks when it encounters symbolic indexing such as `C[i,j,k,l]`.

To overcome this problem, make `C` a SymPy NDimArray:

```
C = sym.tensor.Array(C)
```

---

```
import sympy as sym

Q = sym.MatrixSymbol('Q', 2,2)
C = sym.symarray('C', (2,2,2,2))
i,j,k,l = sym.symbols('i j k l')
C = sym.tensor.Array(C)

print(sym.summation(Q[i,j]*C[i,j,k,l], (i,0,1), (j,0,1), (k,0,1), (l,0,1)))
```

yields

```
C_0_0_0_0*Q[0, 0] + C_0_0_0_1*Q[0, 0] + C_0_0_1_0*Q[0, 0] + C_0_0_1_1*Q[0, 0] + C_0_1_0_0*Q[0, 1] + C_0_1_0_1*Q[0, 1] + C_0_1_1_0*Q[0, 1] + C_0_1_1_1*Q[0, 1] + C_1_0_0_0*Q[1, 0] + C_1_0_0_1*Q[1, 0] + C_1_0_1_0*Q[1, 0] + C_1_0_1_1*Q[1, 0] + C_1_1_0_0*Q[1, 1] + C_1_1_0_1*Q[1, 1] + C_1_1_1_0*Q[1, 1] + C_1_1_1_1*Q[1, 1]
```

---

By the way, `sym.summation(..., (i,0,2))` sums over `i` equaling 0, 1, *and* 2.
In other words, unlike Python's half-open ranges, the sym.summation
range is inclusive on both ends.

`C = sym.symarray('C', (2,2,2,2))` creates a 4-dimensional array with each dimension of length 2. So `C` can only be indexed with 0 and 1, but not 2. So to avoid the index-out-of-range error:

```
ValueError: Index [0, 0, 2, 0] out of border
```

use `sym.summation(..., (i,0,1))`.

Comment: Thank you for the help and corrections. I'm unfortunately still having a bit of trouble. I'm using python 3 which I probably should have mentioned. It seems that Array is not an attribute of tensor anymore; however, there is an array package within tensor. I imported this package and then utilized Array(C) as you suggested. The rest of the code is identical to yours. I still am receiving an error though: "cannot determine truth value of Relational". I should mention I also tried the NDimArray command within the array package.

Comment: I ended up just using symarray and manually defining the summation through loops. Avoiding the summation command seemed to do the trick. Thanks again for the help.